# Loading BDE BPL from another directory

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, bde, bpl

Using Delphi 2010 and a patched version of the BDE I run into a problem loading the BDERTL140.bpl.

Loading DCLBDE140.bpl from another directory then usual works fine. Only when I want to load the BDERTL140.bpl, it always tells me that it has been loaded already from the Windows system directory.

Which packages load the BDERTL140.pbl, and how could I have them load my patched version instead of the original? I would hate to resort to overwriting the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a list of loaded libraries including the complete paths you can run your application under the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), it will output a lot of important information.

You can also use it to show all static dependencies of various DLLs and BPLs, so you should be able to find the first module that forces `BDERTL140.bpl` to be loaded. You should try to load your patched version before that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to place DCLBDE140.bpl in the same directory as your exe, that requires it to avoid loading it from Windows\System32. This is the only way I can figure out, since you can't LoadLibrary it manually.

Comment: As the bpl is loaded at design time, it will be loaded by the IDE. Putting it into the directory of my exe does not help as it is too late. Putting it into the $(BDS)/bin does. Thanks. I would love to have it in another directory though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the folder of your bpl in the front of the windows search path.